# Buttons in Table using PHP/SQL Loop

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, twitter-bootstrap

I have this piece of code:

```
<?php $res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users");
    //If the result of the query has more than 0 rows (1 or more) continue to the loop
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) >0){
        //Loop to organise the data
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            if($row['permission'] == "2"){
                 $perms = '<span class="label label-danger">Administrator</span>';
            } elseif($row['permission'] == "1"){
                 $perms = '<span class="label label-success">Registered User</span>';
            } else {
                 $perms = '<span class="label label-warning">Awaiting Approval</span>';
            }


            //Return the table data
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . $row['telephone'] . "</td><td>" . $perms . "</td>";

        }
   }?>
```

What I want is to add a button in a new column for every row that will activate a piece of code to delete the record in the db.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/IilGIKi.png]

was wondering if someone could assist or point me in the right direction on how to do this. Eventually, there will be a delete button and an approve button that will activate different pieces of SQL code located in the same file. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way:
Insert a button with a post form that will send a variable "delete_id" with the current "user id" from the database.

On top of the code you find a action that delete this if, if it was given through a post form...

It is not very secure, but i would add some security checks like: is number? is valid user id? what is the referal page? ...

```
<?php
if ( $_POST["delete_id"] ) {
    // This action will be performed after click on the Delete button.
    // Better make some security checks here
    $delete_id = htmlspecialchars($_POST["delete_id"]);
    $res = $conn->query("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '$delete_id' LIMIT 1;");
}

$res = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users");
//If the result of the query has more than 0 rows (1 or more) continue to the loop
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) >0){
    //Loop to organise the data
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        if($row['permission'] == "2"){
            $perms = '<span class="label label-danger">Administrator</span>';
        } elseif($row['permission'] == "1"){
            $perms = '<span class="label label-success">Registered User</span>';
        } else {
            $perms = '<span class="label label-warning">Awaiting Approval</span>';
        }
        // Creates a button with POST variable "delete_id" and the value of the "user id"
        $button = '<form method="post" action="' . $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] . '"><input type="hidden" name="delete_id" value="' . $row['id'] . '"><input type="submit" value="Delete this row"></form>';


        //Return the table data
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['firstname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['surname'] . "</td><td>" . $row['email'] . "</td><td>" . $row['username'] . "</td><td>" . $row['telephone'] . "</td><td>" . $perms . "</td><td>" . $button . "</td>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I have edited the code to add what you have suggested. However, I am unable to click the buttons, they are displayed, but not allowing me to click them for the code to execute. Any ideas?